# php encoding and decoding

Tags: php, encoding, decoding

Encoding/Decoding working differentlty on different servers.
Locally I'm running PHP v5.6. default_charset = UTF-8 according to php_info().
When I pass the value `'s` in the URL it displays correctly in an input field as `'s`.

Remotely my Godaddy server is running PHP v5.3, default_charset = No value according to php_info()
When I pass the value 's in the URL it displays incorrectly in the input field as `%27s`.

I have added `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>` in the header of the html file.

Does anyone know how to resolve this so that `'s` displays as `'s` on the remote server?

Comment: that has nothing to do with charsets. it's a proper uri-encoded uri

Comment: I should have noted that I get the same results regardless if I pass the 's through htmlspecialchars() or any other encoding or decoding functions.

Comment: htmlspecialchars is pointless. that's for output into an html context. You're not outputting to a browser, you're outputting to a console. you need `mb_convert_encoding()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to scape the single quote with \' or \'?

Comment: I believe that's only if I'm concerned about saving the value in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

`'` is not a standard alphanumeric character so it gets [URL-encoded with a method similar to this one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for compatibility.

`'` is `%27` hex or `39` decimal ASCII character.

Comment: I get the same results if I pass it through htmlspecialchars() before I display the 's

Comment: Decode the value before processing it farther with http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value through [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) before you display value in input field.